# Cannot connect to AngularFireDatabase

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm attempting to build an Angular Application that pulls data from a Firebase realtime NoSQL database using the latest version of the AngularFire Module. I have been following the docs set out https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/install-and-setup.md and also https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/lists.md. However when I run ng serve, all I can see is a blank page and this error in the console repeated twice: `NullInjectorError: No provider for AngularFireDatabase!`

I've been all through the docs and they seem to be more explicit to connect to Firestore rather than Firebase and not that easy for me to follow. Would much appreciate some help or feedback as to what I could be doing wrong.

Here is my **app.module.ts** file:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { AngularFireStorageModule } from '@angular/fire/storage';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFirestoreModule,
    AngularFireStorageModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

The **app.component.ts** file:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from '@angular/fire/database';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  study_items: Observable<any[]>;
  constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase) {
     this.study_items = db.list('study_items').valueChanges(); 
//      console.log(this);
  }
}
```

The **environment.ts** file:

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  firebase: {
    apiKey: '<my api key because I am not showing it>',
    authDomain: 'my-firebase-demo.firebaseapp.com',
    databaseURL: 'https://my-firebase-demo.firebaseio.com',
    projectId: 'my-firebase-demo',
    storageBucket: 'my-firebase-demo.appspot.com',
    messagingSenderId: '<somenumber>'
  }
};
```

and finally, the **app.component.html** file

```
<ul>
  <li class="text" *ngFor = "let unit of study_items | async">
    {{ unit | json }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Which version do you use? I have AngularFireStore in my providers array, but I dont remember why, could you try to add it?

Comment: I'm using the latest Angular through CLI (v7.0) and the latest AngularFire (v5.1.1). I pretty much pulled everything through using terminal. I have declared the `AngularFirestoreModule` are you saying I should declare one named `AngularFirestore`? I got this working quite easy with old 4.xx version of AngularFire but much has changed.

Comment: After checking your code I found the app.component and app.module being the same :)

Comment: So could you please add your app.component.ts code?

Comment: Sorry about that. Have updated the question

Comment: How did you solve this?